# Improve Less nesting for this rule?

Tags: less

I need the following CSS output. The `ie*` classes must be there for specificity and the `body` class also needs to be there without them as they won't always be added.

```
body.my-class,
html.ie7 body.my-class,
html.ie8 body.my-class,
html.ie9 body.my-class {
  background: red;
}
```

I can get the same thing with this in my Less. However its not a good idea as I have to write the style of `background: red` twice. So if it was updated it would need to be updated in 2 places.

```
body.my-class {
  background: red;
  html.ie7 &,
  html.ie8 &,
  html.ie9 {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Can I write my Less in a different way so that I'm not repeating the style, but so that the compiled CSS is exactly the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add the `&` (parent selector) as one of the comma separated selector list within the top level nesting. Less compiler would automatically replace it with the full parent selector as it always does.

```css
body.my-class {
  &, /* this will replaced with body.my-class as is always the case with parent selectors */
  html.ie7 &,
  html.ie8 &,
  html.ie9 &{
    background: red;
  }
}
```

The above code when compiled would result in exactly the same CSS output as required.

```css
body.my-class,
html.ie7 body.my-class,
html.ie8 body.my-class,
html.ie9 body.my-class {
  background: red;
}
```